Problems with REgEx in Java. Tested on regex101 site
I have a problem that I was not able to solve. I am trying to make a regex match in Java. To develop the regex, I used regex101 site. So the following link shows the developed regex and the content text. There are two matches and thats great.
https://regex101.com/r/gnRMye/1
So, when I use the the following regex in Java:
^Processo\sNº\s[a-zA-Z]{5,9}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}[^a-zA-Z]

It do nor work. The entire Java code follows:
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ValidaRegExFileExemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Processo\sNº\s[a-zA-Z]{5,9}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}[^a-zA-Z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        try {
              File myObj = new File("extrato.txt");
              Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
              while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                // procura match na linha carregada em data
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
                boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
                if (matchFound) {
                    System.out.println(data);
                }
              }
              myReader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}

This code returns nothing. When I use:
^Processo\sNº\s[a-zA-Z]{5,9}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}

It returns:
Processo Nº ATOrd-0148400-36.2009.5.02.0041
Processo Nº ATOrd-0076600-43.2003.5.02.0045
Processo Nº ATOrd-0148400-36.2009.5.02.0043Teste

I would like to do have a match like the first two lines, but not match the last one (Processo Nº ATOrd-0148400-36.2009.5.02.0043Teste).
BTW, the content in extrato.txt is exactly the content of the text in the regex101.com text.
Thanks in advance

You need to double escape \s and friends: Pattern.compile("^Processo\\sNº\\s<etc>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);.

Does this answer your question? Why do I need two slashes in Java Regex to find a "+" symbol?

Note that at your https://regex101.com/r/gnRMye/1 you are using gm flags. The m stands from multi line which lets ^ match start of the line instead of its default behavior which only allows matching start of whole text. So aside from  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE you also may want to use Pattern.MULTILINE flag.

@InSync of course, that question title should say "backslashes"

BTW if your file is not very big, instead of scanning it line by line and creating Matcher for each line, consider reading its entire content to String and then using while(matcher.find()){ String partFound = matcher.group(); ... handle partFound as you like} which is standard approach with Pattern/Matcher.

BUT if you still prefer to use Scanner to manually iterate over each line consider using matcher.match() instead of matcher.find() if you want to ensure that regex matches entire line instead of part of it. You can get rid then ^ and $.

The character $ in a regex means to match the end of a string or line. Add it to the end of your regular expression, and anything that has extra characters after your pattern will no longer match.

Thanks. it works perfectly. I wonder why my pattern developed in reg101.com site worked and the same pattern in Java code did not.

@ricksant "I wonder why my pattern developed in reg101.com site worked and the same pattern in Java code did not" because result of Scanner#nextLine does not contain characters representing line separators at the end of each line. So the the last part of regex [^a-zA-Z] has nothing left to match. This problem doesn't exist on regex101 because there regex engine traverses entire text, not single line. If you try to use that regex on single line but without line separators it will also fail there. Demo https://regex101.com/r/DFSovC/1
